# After restoring ML db, do I need to reindex the MarkLogic DB?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

A database is attached to 3 forests.
The total size of the database is approx 300 GB including indexes (created lot of indexes).

I have to migrate the data to another server, To do this I am just taking the backup of the entire database and restoring it to another db in another MarkLogic instance.

My question is after restoring, is it required to Re-index the DB? if yes, is there any way to avoid Re-indexing as re-indexing is taking a lot of time (approx 15 hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A restore does not in itself necessitate a reindex. But restoring to a database with a different configuration would be cause for a reindex.

You can turn reindexing on and off in the database configuration or (better) set it to throttle itself to work less aggressively.